# Получить все записи MySQL при определенном условии

Tags: mysql

Всем привет. Есть база данных. Транспорт: id, transport и фото транспорта id, id_transport, photo. Некоторые транспорта есть без фото, как получить все записи у которых есть фото?

Comment: `Select * from ... where photo is not null`?

Comment: так photo и trasport в разных таблицах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё зависит от того, какого типа ваше поле `photo`. Например, если это строка, которая хранит адрес URL для фотографии, то запрос может быть таким:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM transport_tbl
WHERE transport_tbl.id = photo_tbl.id_transport 
AND photo_tbl.photo IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Странно, что то не получается(

Comment: @duddeniska, добавьте в пост описание схемы обеих таблиц, так будет более понятно, что нужно

Comment: проблема в том что он дублирует записи, так как в photo может быть несколько фотографий к одному транспорту.((( что делать?

Comment: @duddeniska, добавьте в запрос DISTINCT (см. ответ, он изменён)

Comment: уау магия, что такое DISTINCT пойду читать)))

Comment: @duddeniska, вот пример: http://oooportal.ru/?cat=article&id=1232 :)